# Missing an complete nested object while using confluent kafka-S3 connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using confluent kafka s3 connector to index my files to s3 bucket. I have my customisation included. Recently I noticed randomly for few records partial nested field is missing. This is completely random, I tried doing some logging but no use, logs print the exact json document but when it's being saved to S3 we see a part of nested object is missing.
I am mainly concentrating on the write and commit function of RecordWriter class used. The main issue is it's completely random in nature, a simple re-crawl is solving the issue but in long run this will not help out. Any solutions or suggestion where I can look into will be helpful. Below are the connector properties I am using

```
name=s3-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
topics=s3_sink_event_test
s3.region=us-west-2
s3.part.size=5242880
flush.size=1
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
locale=en-US
timezone=UTC
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
rotate.schedule.interval.ms=3600000
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
s3.bucket.name=test-kafka-s3-sink
#format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
format.class=com.practice.data.CustomFormatter
timestamp.extractor=com.practice.data.CustomTimeStampExtracter
partitioner.class=com.practice.data.CustomColumnPartitioner
```

Thanks
Ashit

Comment: Have you tried not using using the byte array value converter and actually using the JSON one?

Comment: Didn't tried that ? But is there any reason you feel that because of byte array converter we are missing the data. I can test something on this line but wanted to know why you think json converter will be good. @OneCricketeer

Comment: You're trying to use JSONFormat class to create JSON files so why not deserialize to JSON first? I'm not saying it'll fix any missing records, but it'll aide in deserialization, assuming that's where the problem is